# Stop all processes and services from accessing a specific folder in Windows (and keep them out)

Tags: windows, taskmanager, access-rights, windows-process

in Windows Server 2008 I need to stop every process accessing a specific folder in order to apply some changes. Then i need to restore all the stopped processes.
Is there any tool that can do that? Would it be possible to do it using a .bat or .vbs file? I am not talking about finding the processes and killing them using the task manager. I need something that would do it automatically whenever needed.
Also i need those processes to be blocked while i am working there and only be revoked or grant access after i finish the job.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but it sounds like you want the Restart Manager API.

Comment: Well what more info should  i provide? I have a bunch of applications and processes accessing a folder and i want to stop them dynamically. How can i do it? The folder is my Oracle Home directory and i want to apply a PSU update but this shouldnt make any difference as it is not only the Oracle processes that are accessing this folder. What do you mean by restarting the Manager API?

Comment: That's "Restart Manager API", an API named "Restart Manager", designed to allow processes to co-operate to avoid needing to restart the computer when updating software.  But from the sounds of it it won't help anyway - in my experience Oracle software isn't sophisticated enough to be likely to support it.  Not sure why non-Oracle software would be touching your Oracle Home?  (Or do you mean software not written by Oracle but that has Oracle components embedded into it?)

Comment: Anyway, there's no silver bullet here, the only thing I can think of that might help is to reboot into Safe Mode.  Or perhaps relocate the folder, or change permissions so only one account has access?  You'd probably still need to reboot though, to get rid of existing handles.  I suppose Oracle might have a tool to help with this, but that's off-topic here - and if non-Oracle software is involved (depending on what you mean by that) it probably wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: ... although on second thoughts, doesn't the same problem affect everyone who uses Oracle?  I'd have thought there must be a standard solution.  You might be better off asking on Oracle's own support forums, or perhaps Server Fault.

Comment: Orcale would have some downtime by the patch application anyway... the point is that doing the process with a script this time is reduced.

Comment: The problem is solved by using a script that changes the acess rights to the folder and then taskills all the handles. Thank you very much!